# I'm convinced my professor is incorrectly saying that this matrix is NOT row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

So the reason as to why I'm confused is because I'm seeing the conditions required for a matrix to be in row echelon form and I can't imagine how this matrix doesn't satisfy them all.

Maybe it's because there can only be 1 zero row? But then again, the condition states that all zero rows are at the bottom, which is the case for this matrix.

Am I wrong? And if so could you please explain why I'm really confused.

\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}

EDIT: SORRY I meant to say he thinks its NOT in row echelon form sorry

Comment: So the professor says it is in row echelon form and you agree with them?  Why the question?

Comment: The matrix is in row echelon form because every row of all zeroes is at the bottom and all entries below the only leading entry are zero. I’m not sure what your question is; both of you seem to agree.

Comment: What conditions have you used for this? There is no restriction on the number of rows of all zeros.

Comment: Please proofread your question. Is your professor saying this matrix is *not* in row echelon form?

Comment: The part of the definition of "row echelon form" addressing zero rows only requires that *all* rows consisting only of zeroes be at the bottom; there is no restriction about the number of such rows. A zero matrix is in row echelon form, regardless of the number of rows it has.

Comment: @TedShifrin@Arturo I will delete my comments so as to not to cause more confusion and misinformation. I didn't realize we had those extra conditions.

Comment: @Randall Sorry I meant to say my professor is saying it's not in row echelon form, but I think it is no?

Comment: This matrix is in row echelon form, and also in reduced row echelon form.  There is one pivot, it is a $1$, there is nothing above it and there are $0$'s below it.  The second column has no pivot, so the $2$ doesn't matter.

Comment: @daruma: I've removed my comment as well. Note that you cannot "ping" more than one person per comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The matrix is in (reduced) row echelon form. (See all the comments above!)

Comment: Great thank you!